# How to turn off the default behaviour of mouse enter on the surface plot of ilnumerics?

Tags: ilnumerics

When I move the mouse over the surface plot of the ilnumerics, the color of the plot turns to pink. This seems to be the default behaviour. How can this be turned off?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
surface.Markable = false
```

The Markable property is a property of every node. Here, 'surface' is expected to reference the group node which is created by

```
var surface = new ILNumerics.Drawing.Plotting.ILSurface(...)
```

Alternatively, the hover marking can be switched on / off individually for the wireframe lines and the surface fill:

```
surface.Fill.Markable = false;
surface.Wireframe.Markable = false;
```

Comment: Vote for turning this into default behavior.